# Use two instances of the same model for foreignkeys on the same model in Django

Tags: python, django

I need to be able to store two ManyToManyFields referring two account model objects. 
acctId_from should refer to the account object that the transaction was from, 
acctId_to should refer to the account object that the transaction was sent to. 
This is how I'm doing it:

```
class transaction(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    acctId_from = models.ManyToManyField(account, related_name="acctfrom")
    acctId_to = models.ManyToManyField(account, related_name="acctto")
    amount = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
```

I have also tried using plain ForeignKeys which also returned the same error.

I am using related names but I'm not sure why I'm still getting this error:

```
login.transaction.account_from: (fields.E304) Reverse accessor 'account.transaction' for 'login.transaction.account_from' clashes with reverse accessor for 'login.transaction.account_to'.
```

Comment: Did you run migrations again? Because the error refers to `account_from` **but** neither the field name (`acctId_from`) nor the related_name (`"acctfrom"`) is called like that. Are there maybe more fields that you did not add to this post?